# Docker does not autostart every time

Tags: docker, autostart

Running Ubuntu desktop as server as a VM on ESXI and have Docker running there and Home assistant.

**The problem is -** When power source breaks, the machine autorestarts, VM reboots, but docker does not always boot up and Home assistant doesn't work either.

When I type in

`sudo docker ps`

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running
```

Then I got to ESXI - hit restart and all works like a charm.
What can it be guys?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the docker service to run it automatically when the system restarts. The command is:

```
sudo systemctl enable docker
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you, i tried that and got this line

Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/docker.service → /lib/systemd/system/docker.service.

i guess this should help me out.
but i still don't understand why it autostarted sometimes, and sometimes not

Comment: Please explan how this solves the problem described at the top of this page or delete this post for being not-an-answer.